# Prove that the straight lines whose direction cosines are given by the relations

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

Prove that the straight lines whose direction cosines are given by the relations $al+bm+cn=0$ and $fmn+gnl+hlm=0$ are perpendicular if $\dfrac {f}{a} +\dfrac {g}{b} + \dfrac {h}{c}=0$ and parallel if $\sqrt {af} \pm \sqrt {bg} \pm \sqrt {ch}=0$

My Attempt:

Given relations are 
$$al+bm+cn=0$$
$$fmn+gnl+hlm=0$$
Eliminating $n$ between these two equations, we get
$$fm (-\dfrac {al+bm}{c}) + g(-\dfrac {al+bm}{c})l + hlm=0$$
$$agl^2+(af+bg-ch)lm+bfm^2=0$$
$$ag(\dfrac {l}{m})^2 + (ch-af+bg) (\dfrac {l}{m}) + bf=0$$

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the question? There are a lot of letters but no indication which of them are related to the direction cosines of the straight lines.

Comment: @user I think the direction cosines are represented by $l,m,n$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohris But there should  be at least two sets of the direction cosines. If two lines have the same direction cosines $(l,m,n) $ they are  parallel.

Comment: @user The two sets are given by the solutions of the two equations

Comment: @ShubhamJohri This does not look convincing taking into account the possibility of "parallel" solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to work with direction ratios to test perpendicularity and parallelism. Note that $l\ne0$, because $l=0\implies m=n=l=0$ assuming $f\ne0$. Divide the first equation by $l$ and the second by $l^2$,$$a+b\frac ml+c\frac nl=0\\f\frac ml\frac nl+g\frac nl+h\frac ml=0$$Substitute $\frac ml=x,\frac nl=y$ and solve the resulting system of equations. The required direction ratios will then be $(1,x_1,y_1),(1,x_2,y_2)$ for which the conditions for perpendicularity $(1+x_1x_2+y_1y_2=0)$ and parallelism $(\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{y_1}{y_2}=1)$ can be easily derived.

The formulae for sum and product of roots of a quadratic will help in getting the conditions without having to solve the quadratic.

Comment: I didn't understand why $l=0$ and $l=m=n=0$? Why assuming $f\neq 0$?

Comment: When $l=0,fmn+gnl+hlm=fmn=0\implies f\ne0\wedge(m=0\vee n=0)\vee f=0$. When $f\ne0\wedge m=0$, using the first equation, $al+bm+cn=cn=0\implies n=0$. Similarly when $f\ne0\wedge n=0$.

Comment: I get the cases when $f\neq 0$ as described just above; that if so, both m and n would be 0. But how do you conclude f=0 never happens from *that*?

Comment: @HarryHolmes All we need to consider is that at-least one of $f,g,h$ is non-zero since if they are all zero, we only have the first equation which represents a plane passing through the origin. Even with the additional equation $l^2+m^2+n^2=1$, we would have infinitely many solutions. Suppose $g\ne0$. Then you would have to divide by $m$.

Comment: That makes sense, great. Also, I suppose we just have to assume a, b, and c are all non-zero, right?

Comment: @HarryHolmes Even though that is not explicitly stated we can infer it because $a,b,c$ are written in the denominator.

Comment: Yeah, I expected that. Thanks a lot!